# Secure FTP from HP-UX to remote FTP server

Tags: ftp, sftp, hp-ux

I have a secure FTP server I need to connect to from a HP-UX box. This will be via a script. An attempt from the HP-UX box using the terminal fails because it is not a SFTP connection.

If I fire up a browser from another box & type in https://ftp-servers-address I get connected & prompted for credentials.

How to do SFTP from a HP-UX box to this external site?

TIA.

Comment: Have you established a private/public key pair from your HPUX box to the external site?  Once that's set, you should just be able to put in "sftp some.server.com" to connect to it.  At least that's how it's worked for me when using SFTP...

Comment: This article shows how to generate an RSA (private/public) key pair - http://www.aixmind.com/?p=1083

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about two different things: SFTP vs FTPS. SFTP is SSH FTP, and FTPS is FTP over SSL. Both are forms of secure FTP although implemented using different encryption techniques.

According to your URL, you want a FTPS client (not a SFTP client). For that you could use [LFTP](http://lftp.yar.ru) or any other FTPS client you want and then work out the SSL certificates. In case you really want a SFTP client, then you could use [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org) and work out the SSH keys.

I hope this helps.